# "Disk you attached not readable" - PMBR/MBR corrupted?

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition

Background:

Purchased 2 12TB WD Gold drives about 2 years ago and have been using them in an external enclosure without problem.

After upgrading my Mac mini server to 11.4, the message "The disk you attached is not readable" was displayed for this one drive post-boot. All other attached drives are fine, including it's twin 12TB drive. The message follows the bad drive to other Macs.

Both 12TB drives are encrypted and APFS. They're simply used for storage, so they've never been partitioned or set up for booting.

Since I have a twin drive (note: not a RAID pair, just an identical physical drive), I've compared them side by side, and the main issue that I've found so far is that it appears that the PMBR in sector 0 has been corrupted somehow.

Here's output from gpt for the ***bad*** drive:

```
New-iMac:~ user$ sudo gpt -vv -r show /dev/disk2
Password:
gpt show: /dev/disk2: mediasize=12000138625024; sectorsize=512; blocks=23437770752
gpt show: /dev/disk2: MBR not found at sector 0
gpt show: /dev/disk2: Pri GPT at sector 1
gpt show: /dev/disk2: Sec GPT at sector 23437770751
        start         size  index  contents
            0            1         
            1            1         Pri GPT header
            2           32         Pri GPT table
           34            6         
           40       409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
       409640  23437098928      2  GPT part - 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  23437508568       262151         
  23437770719           32         Sec GPT table
  23437770751            1         Sec GPT header
```

The good, twin drive:

```
iMac:~ user$ sudo gpt -vv -r show /dev/disk5
Password:
gpt show: /dev/disk5: mediasize=12000138625024; sectorsize=512; blocks=23437770752
gpt show: /dev/disk5: PMBR at sector 0
gpt show: /dev/disk5: Pri GPT at sector 1
gpt show: /dev/disk5: Sec GPT at sector 23437770751
        start         size  index  contents
            0            1         PMBR
            1            1         Pri GPT header
            2           32         Pri GPT table
           34            6         
           40       409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
       409640  23437098928      2  GPT part - 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  23437508568       262151         
  23437770719           32         Sec GPT table
  23437770751            1         Sec GPT header
```

When I look at sector 0 on the *good* drive, I see what appear to be good/reasonable values when using iBored (old time Mac disk too which can read disk sectors, and show values for MBR partition table).

[image: iBored MBR output - good disk]

When I look at sector 0 on the *bad* drive, it (sector 0 only) is zeroed out completely.

All of the remaining sectors appear to be present (some other corruption notwithstanding). That is, data exists where I would expect it to exist and zeros exist where I expect zeros to exist. You can see that besides sector 0, gpt generates the exact same output that the good disk does.

My intuition - *which I freely admit could be completely wrong* - is that I may be able to edit sector 0 on the bad drive to match the values found on the good drive and then be able to at least try to mount the drive at that point.

However, I haven't done anything yet other than looking. TIA for any help!

Comment: @Tetsujin: There is a Protective Master Boot Record (PMBR) table. This table contains a single partition entry which encompasses the all sectors other than the sector 0 (which is the MBR itself). In the case of a 12 TB drive, the partition size is as large as can possibly fit in the table (which is 4,294,967,294 sectors). The purpose of the PMBR table is to fool legacy software in to thinking there is no free space on the drive.

Comment: sixty2: I agree with your intuition. The values you show in your iBored image are correct for the MBR of the good drive. There is no reason not to use this MBR to replace the MBR on the bad drive.

Comment: I'm on business travel this week so I'll give this a whirl when I get back. What is the technical process going on with the OS when a disk is powered up - is this PMBR being accessed, and would a corrupted one logically cause the OS to display the "disk inserted is not readable" message? Once again, TIA

Comment: OK - for now, editing sector 0 on the bad drive seems to have done the trick. It does as me for the password, and it mounts. I can see all of the data, and everything opens as it should. Any other checks I should run at this point?

Answer (score 1):

Editing sector 0 (the PMBR) of the bad drive to fix the corruption fixed the issue, at least for now. I can see/open/edit all files so far.

There's still a chance of hw failure, even though the disk passes all firmware checks and "disk repair" completes successfully.

I was lucky to have an identical disk which had been treated in an identical manner so I could use those values in the first sector.

Believe this may have been precipitated by a few power outages that hit this server in the weeks preceding the failure, but that's just a guess.

Comment: I know you were look for something more from us here a Ask Different. However, your question included the answer and therefore there was not much more to add. BTW, the values in the MBR for drives over 2 TB with a 512 byte sector size are the same. So, if you did not have the identical disk, then an answer could have been post showing what values you needed to use.

Comment: Actually I was quite happy with the information I got (and have gotten) here. The way Ask Different is set up required me to do research first, much of which I was able to accomplish by looking at past answer. Then I needed to post in a logical way and support my assumptions/guesses. I then got confirmation of what I needed to have enough confidence to continue (hex editing content on a large HD is... fun). So, it's all good and I have my data back, and anyone looking for this or a similar answer in the future will now have this thread to find.